# Openshift DIY cartridige with Tomcat 8 and JDK 8. JAVAHOME subscribe

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift, openshift-cartridge

It is the first time I use OpenShift and am creating an application DIY cartridge with Tomcat Java 8 and 8.

I am using

```
export JAVA_HOME="${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}jdk1.8.0_51"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/bin
./startup.sh
```

command on my hook **action_hook/start** to start Tomcat 8 automatically and change the variable JAVA_HOME my application to run the java 8. The command to run the tomcat 8 is working perfectly, but to change the JAVA_HOME variable seems is not working.

But if I run the command to change the JAVA_HOME variable in my ssh console (Putty) and soon after give the `java -version` command, it shows that the version is 1.8.x But when I close my shh console, open again and I run the `java -version` command, it returns the version 1.7.x. Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is not set by default when using the DIY cartridge, you should try setting it using the `rhc env set` (https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#custom-variables) command instead of using a script in your action_hooks directory.

Something like:

```
rhc env set JAVA_HOME=/var/lib/openshift/<app-id>/app-root/data/jdk1.8.0_51 -a <appname>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you =)